# how do you edit the default php linter for vscode?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

With, `ESLint` for JS, there is functionality for returning an error for value assigned OR defined but never used variables.  i.e

```
file: 'file:///home/mov-list.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: ''bar' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)'
at: '11,5'
source: 'eslint'
```

|

```
file: 'file:///home/ajax222/mov-list.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: ''foo' is assigned a value but never used. (no-unused-vars)'
at: '20,5'
source: 'eslint'
```

And from here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php . Vscode is shipped with a default PHP linter.

**Question: Which file and what code should i add to the default PHP linter to return errors for both:**
1. Variables declared but never used.
2. Varibles assigned a value but never used.
Just like it works with ESlint.
Or should i just look out for other specific PHP linters ?

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_linting), VS Code uses the default php linter by default. If you want to make improvements to the official php linter, you can reach out [on github](https://github.com/php/php-src) to the php developers.

There are two other linters on the vscode marketplace, one that uses [php code sniffer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs) and one that uses [php md](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=linyang95.phpmd).

Phpmd should catch what you want as described [here](https://phpmd.org/rules/index.html#unused-code-rules), but you can also create [custom rules](https://phpmd.org/documentation/creating-a-ruleset.html):

> Unused Code Rules
>
> UnusedPrivateField: Detects when a private field is declared and/or assigned a value, but not used.
>
> UnusedLocalVariable: Detects when a local variable is declared and/or assigned, but not used.
>
> UnusedPrivateMethod: Unused Private Method detects when a private method is declared but is unused.
>
> UnusedFormalParameter: Avoid passing parameters to methods or constructors and then not using those parameters.

If you don't like phpmd and the codesniffer linter doesn't do what you need, it can also be extended as described [here](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml).

Comment: i have taken the time to read about your suggestion and it sounds very promising....in particular (`php md`). Though i took a few reads on google that running two linters at ago isn't good practice in terms of consistency. I just dont know if i can have it both ways i.e Run the  official php linter but also enjoy the features that come with `php md`...